# Seaborn pairplot not displaying in matrix form

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a DataFrame with the variables below. I am trying to find the relationship by  plotting "profit" with other variables excluding "Date".

- Date
- Billable_Fixed Bid
- Billable_Time_Material
- Billable_Transaction_Based
- Non_Billable
- Indirect_Costs
- Unbilled_CP_and_AM
- Direct_Costs
- Profit

Code:

```
cols = [
  'Billable_Fixed Bid',
  'Billable_Time_Material', 
  'Billable_Transaction_Based', 
  'Non_Billable', 
  'Unbilled_CP_and_AM',
  'Direct_Costs'
]

sns.pairplot(data1,x_vars=cols,y_vars='Profit',size =5,kind='reg')
```

Problem is the plots are getting displayed in a single line, which is not clearly visible.

I want it to display 2 plots per line so that it is clearly visible.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Hence the only thing I can tell you is to better use `FacetGrid` with the `col_wrap` argument.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment: Using `FacetGrid` with `col_wrap=2` will solve your problem. Check the examples in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html?highlight=facetgrid).